# Any idea as to how to tackle this error as I am quite new to this: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [150, 4]

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

flowers = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Samuel Mireku/Desktop/iris.csv')

#print(flowers.head(5))

# Headers for columns
#print(flowers.columns)

#reads a specific column in ascending(0) or decscending(1)
#print(flowers.sort_values(['sepal_length_cm'], ascending=[0]))

#filtering data
#print(flowers.loc[(flowers['sepal_length_cm'] > 5)]),



targ = flowers['flow_fam'].replace(['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica'], [0,1,2], inplace = True)

print(flowers.loc[(flowers['flow_fam'] == 1)])



y = flowers.iloc[:4]
X = flowers.iloc[:,0:3]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=27)

print(flowers.X_train)
```

errors:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [150, 4]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you forgot `,` in first `iloc` - `y = flowers.iloc[:,4]` - and it makes your problem